# Navigation with Remote on EPG

Tags: android, android-tv, d-pad, epg

this is the method to scroll and navigate on my EPG, but i need to navigate with Remote on AndroidTV.

I've read few things about setClickable, setFocusable but its working only on the main screen and i need to give inside to access each cells.

So basically, i need to navigate between cells inside the EPG.

Anyone has any ideas how?

The EPG project is there -> https://github.com/korre/android-tv-epg

```
private class OnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

        // This is absolute coordinate on screen not taking scroll into account.
        int x = (int) e.getX();
        int y = (int) e.getY();

        // Adding scroll to clicked coordinate
        int scrollX = getScrollX() + x;
        int scrollY = getScrollY() + y;

        int channelPosition = getChannelPosition(scrollY);
        if (channelPosition != -1 && mClickListener != null) {
            if (calculateResetButtonHitArea().contains(scrollX,scrollY)) {
                // Reset button clicked
                mClickListener.onResetButtonClicked();
            } else if (calculateChannelsHitArea().contains(x, y)) {
                // Channel area is clicked
                /*mClickListener.onChannelClicked(channelPosition, epgData.getChannel(channelPosition));*/
            } else if (calculateProgramsHitArea().contains(x, y)) {
                // Event area is clicked
                int programPosition = getProgramPosition(channelPosition, getTimeFrom(getScrollX() + x - calculateProgramsHitArea().left));
                if (programPosition != -1) {
                    /*mClickListener.onEventClicked(channelPosition, programPosition, epgData.getEvent(channelPosition, programPosition));*/

                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        int dx = (int) distanceX;
        int dy = (int) distanceY;
        int x = getScrollX();
        int y = getScrollY();


        // Avoid over scrolling
        if (x + dx < 0) {
            dx = 0 - x;
        }
        if (y + dy < 0) {
            dy = 0 - y;
        }
        if (x + dx > mMaxHorizontalScroll) {
            dx = mMaxHorizontalScroll - x;
        }
        if (y + dy > mMaxVerticalScroll) {
            dy = mMaxVerticalScroll - y;
        }

        scrollBy(dx, dy);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                           float vX, float vY) {

        mScroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), -(int) vX,
                -(int) vY, 0, mMaxHorizontalScroll, 0, mMaxVerticalScroll);

        redraw();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
}
```